# 502 Bad Gateway Using Nginx, Gunicorn and Flask

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm learning to deploy my Flask app onto an Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance and am following the [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04). I'm and am encountering one final issue: I'm got my Gunicorn booted up and working using this command: `gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:project.sock -m 007 wsgi:app` to create 3 worker threads and a socket called `project.sock`.

```
[2018-02-23 17:14:49 +0000]  [INFO] Booting worker with pid: X
[2018-02-23 17:14:49 +0000] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: X
[2018-02-23 17:14:49 +0000]  [INFO] Booting worker with pid: X
Connection initialized.
Connection initialized.
Connection initialized.
```

But I'm encountering errors when attempting to have Nginx connect to my `project.sock` from Gunicorn- a `502 Bad Gateway error`.

Here's my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/project` configurations:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MY_SERVER_DNS;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/flaskapp_dev/my_project/project.sock;
    }
}
```

A check of the Nginx error logs shows that it's getting a `Permission denied` error attempting to connect to my `project.sock`:

```
      2018/02/23 17:26:46 [crit] 10822#10822: *4 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject/myproject.sock failed 
(13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, 
        client: CLIENT_IP, server: MY_SERVER_DNS, 
        request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
    upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject/project.sock:/", host: "MY_SERVER_DNS"
```

I know there's been plenty of SO posts on this question, but I'm noticing that most of them revolve around `uwsgi`, which I'm not using here. I suspect that it's obviously a permission issue, so I tried `chmod 711 /home/ubuntu/myproject/project` and restarting nginx, but that results in the same `502 Bad Gateway error`.

The [closest SO post to my issue appears to be this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500930/nginx-502-bad-gateway-on-gunicorn-proxy-flask-app), but it has no answers or comments.

Comment: First try with 777 and see if that fixes the issue or not. If not then we look at other options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a permissions issue. Nginx that's running under one user cannot get access to unix socket that's owned by another user. I recommend to run nginx server and gunicorn under the same user so unix socket created by gunicron will be accessed by nginx without any problems. `chmod 777` is a temporal solution that can show that there is only permission issue if after executing this command the described problem has gone, but it's better to initially run nginx and gunicorn under the same user. Also it's better to specify full path to unix socket to avoid "no such file or directory" possible issue: `gunicorn --workers 3 --bind <full_path_to_unix_socket_to_be_created>`